# RGB24 Error in SubRip,AVISubDetector,AviSynth

Tags: avi, subtitle

Basically, I want to extract `burnt-in` subtitle from a movie ,which is mp4. I am very new with this stuff, So I got `SubRip` and `AviSynth` and converted the movie in `.avi` , but when I try to open it with `SubRip` I get this

> "LoadPlugin("d:\data\dgdecode.dll") 
>   DirectShowSource("C:\UniConverter\Converted\bzc50.avi", 23.976, true,
>   false, true)  ConvertToRGB24()

Then I down. `AviSubDetector` ,but then I got
 "

> error in FrameOpen- Conversion to RGB24 not available. Check that you
>   have required codec installed" .

So I don't know exactly what are those required codec but I google it ffms2 and `dgmpgdec`. I don't know how to do this 'cuz I can't find anything on google, so maybe you guys can help me do this.

Thx all <3